# How can i make all array values in variable

Tags: php, arrays

i want to make all array values in one variable

**Example:**

i have a title

```
$title = "my name is medo";
$words = explode(' ', $title);
```

**The result is a**

```
$words['0'] = my
$words['1'] = name 
$words['2'] = is 
$words['3'] = medo
```

i want to make it like that

```
$allwords = "my,name,is,medo";
```

thanks all

Comment: `$allwords = implode(",", $allwords);`

Comment: So you just want to replace each space in the string with a comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
implode ( "," , $words );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with string functions, which is much easier for  your case.

```
$originalString = "my name is medo";
$finalString = str_replace(" ", ",", $originalString);
```